# Does Joomla have shortcodes like Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, joomla

In wordpress we have shortcodes that let us place info inside html without using any programming like php or javascript. That's a great feature, as it allow us to be safer when we need to do simple things.

Example (Not real, just an example!), let's say I have the following text `The current user is [myusername], and is allowed to do all sort of things in the website.` inserted in WYSIWYG editor, while editing an article, then I save and open the article on the site's frontpage, here's what I get:

> The current user is `admin`,  and is allowed to do all sort of things
>   in the website.

Get it?

I wonder if joomla has something like that too. Any ideas?

UPDATE: The only shortcodes I know in Joomla are template related and are for styling only.

Comment: The closest thing is really a content plugin, which would be entered by surrounding the relevant information with `{}`  such as to load a module or module position, to add a map etc.  It would be cool to make a content plugin that would do that. Basically the plugins do a regex on the content body and replace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Natively Joomla! (3.4) doesn't implement shortcode in content input.

However, you can easily add this feature with an extension. If you google something like "joomla extension shortcode" you will find multiple solutions. [Shortcode Ultimate](http://extensions.joomla.org/browse/new/extension/authoring-a-content/content-construction/shortcode-ultimate) seems to be what you are looking for.

Moreover, some extensions propose their own shortcode system (for example the excellent component for newsletter, Acymailing) for their particular purpose.

Comment: I know there are extensions for that kind of thing, but I needed to know if Joomla had it by default.